# Is there a setting or good add-in for Visual Studio to color lines (like Throw) in the editor?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

Is there a setting (didn't find one of hand) or good add-in (SO is better for recommendations than Google) for Visual Studio to color lines specially in the editor depending on what keywords or statements it contains?

For example, if a line contains "Throw", it'd be nice to see either that word or the line in red, similarly for "Debug.Assert" (yellow would look nice), and return...ok, maybe my screen would look like a rainbow if I went that far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any specific add-ins, but this could be achieved with a simple [DXCore](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/) plugin.

Comment: Welcome to the addiction that is SO!

Answer (score 0):

In VS2005, click Tools, Options, Environment, Fonts and Colors. There are settings for many different kinds of text element, allowing code to be colored to help indicate syntax.

The default settings are subtle, but cue a lot more useful information than you are noticing at first glance. It is easy to go overboard...

It doesn't look like its possible to give individual keywords distinct properties, and IMHO that would be a bad idea to do in any case.

Other programmer's editors provide similar capabilities.